# How to get only the first sequence of numbers in a listing using batch or powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

What I need is the first sequence of a number in a listing:

The command:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in (notas.txt) do @echo %%a
```

Returns:

```
Compra cfme NF 12345 de 123 CIA ABC
Pgto dupl. 12345 - 123 CIA ABC
Compra cfme NFS 654321-CIA CBC
Pgto NF 654321 de CIA CBC
```

But what I need is:

```
12345
12345
654321
654321
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you want to extract just any digits numbers with 5 or more in length ?

Comment: No the first numeric sequence no matter how many digits.

Answer (score 3):

There are numerous PowerShell solution/techniques that can perform what is required.

The switch statement can be used with the `-File` and `-Regex` parameters.

```
switch -Regex -File notas.txt {
  '\d+' { $Matches[0] }
}
```

You can also use the `Match` method from the regex class:

```
Get-Content notas.txt | Foreach-Object {
    [regex]::Match($_,'\d+').Value
}
```

Both solutions rely on regex matching with `\d+` matching one or more consecutive digits. Since we are doing a single match per line, the first match is the only match returned. The regex class method `Matches` returns multiple matches per string input.

Comment: i've been told that the `switch` construct with the `-File` parameter is _much faster_ than the `Get-Content` technique. does that agree with your experience?

Comment: @Lee_Dailey: Yes, `switch` is much faster than `Get-Content` + `ForEach-Object`, for a variety of reasons (no cmdlets involved, no pipeline overhead, no decorating of input strings with provider properties).

Answer (score 0):

With a Batch file using regex in vbscript you can do something like this : 
[Demo Here](https://regex101.com/r/PEzage/1)

```bat
@echo off & color 0A
Title Extract Numbers from String using Regex with vbscript
Set "InputFile=%~dp0notas.txt"
Set "OutPutFile=%~n0_OutPutFile.txt"
Call :Extract_Number "%InputFile%" CON
Call :Extract_Number "%InputFile%" "%OutPutFile%"
TimeOut /T 3 /NoBreak>nul 
If Exist "%OutPutFile%" Start "" "%OutPutFile%" & Exit
::-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
:Extract_Number <Input> <OutPut>
(
echo WScript.StdOut.WriteLine Extract_Number(Data^)
echo Function Extract_Number(Data^)
echo      Data = "%~1" 
echo      Data = WScript.StdIn.ReadAll 
echo      Set re = New RegExp 
echo      re.Global = True 
echo      re.IgnoreCase = True  
echo      re.Pattern = "\d{5,}" 
echo      For Each Match in re.Execute(Data^) 
echo          Number = Number ^& Match.Value ^& vbCrLF
echo      Next  
echo     Extract_Number = Number
echo End Function
)>"%tmp%\%~n0.vbs"
cscript //nologo "%tmp%\%~n0.vbs" < "%~1" > "%~2"
If Exist "%tmp%\%~n0.vbs" Del "%tmp%\%~n0.vbs"
Exit /B
::----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Thanks, vbscript seems to have way much more functionalities than batch, I hope to learn it some day.

Answer (score 0):

This first code does what your question asks, but not what your expected results show:

```
@echo off

:: Pass the entire line to a subroutine
for /f "delims=" %%a in (notas.txt) do call :process %%a

goto :eof


:process
:: Check if we've evaluated the entire line
if "%1"=="" (
   echo No number was found in this line
   goto :eof
)

:: Check if the current parameter is only numbers
:: If it is, then echo and move on to the next line
:: If not, use shift to evaluate the next parameter
echo %1|findstr /i /r "[^0-9]" >nul && shift && goto :process
echo %1
goto :eof
```

2 things.  First, I don't know what you want to do if a number isn't found in the line.  In the code above I just echo "No number was found in this line".
Second, I presumed "number" to be fully delimited with standard spaces as delimiters.  Thus, the code above does **NOT** return `654321` from the line `Compra cfme NFS 654321-CIA CBC` because `654321-CIA` is not a number *delimited by spaces*.  If you want additional delimiters, then change this line above:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in (notas.txt) do call :process %%a
```

to:

```
for /f "tokens=1-10 delims=-., " %%a in (notas.txt) do call :process %%a %%b %%c %%d %%e %%f %%g %%h %%i %%j
```

adding whatever delimiters you want (don't forget a space before the double quote).  This line is good for up to 10 entries on a given line.  Going up to 26 using `tokens=1-26` and `%%a` through `%%z` is pretty easy.
Finally -- if you want to pull a non-delimited number -- then that would be a completely different approach.  An example would be getting `1356` from `PC1356 NLA LOA`; or getting `35232` from `PC LI-D 35232NDA TTH`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My intention was to output something like this to a csv file:

Pgto dupl. 12345 - 123 CIA ABC,12345
Compra cfme NFS 654321-CIA CBC,654321

And then import it to excel, thanks to you and others that helped me I managed to complete the task, thanks.